# Obtain the referrer path in PHP

Tags: php, referrer

I have a only one .php (`root/process.php`) file for multiple languages

```
root/en/command.htm 
root/fr/command.htm 
root/ru/command.htm
```

and so one. However, for each of commands I have a `thankYou.htm` in the same folder:

```
root/en/thankYou.htm 
root/fr/thankYou.htm 
root/ru/thankYou.htm
```

How do I redirect the page after processing it in the `process.php`?

```
// redirect to a thank you page
header("Location: " .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']. "\thankYou.htm");
```

this does not work: Error 404. Normally, if the referrer is `root/ru/command.htm` by e.g., so the php should sent user to `root/ru/thankYou.htm` etc.

Comment: Consider describing what *does* happen instead of saying "does not work".

Comment: @Ignacio: I obtain 404. Normally, the referer is root/en/command.htm, so the php should sent user to root/en/thankYou.htm

Comment: Knowing which URL gives the 404 is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a slash instead a backslash:

```
header("Location: " .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. "/thankYou.htm");
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTTP it's misspelled as "referer", so you want `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.